# NDSolve - interpolation or machine precision problem

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, warning-messages

For the following equations;
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \text{NN}(t)}{\partial t}&=-\frac{(c \times\text{Sigma})}{\pi\times  L\times \text{Omega}^2} \text{NN}(t) \times\text{Phi}(t)-\frac{\text{NN}(t)}{\text{Tau0}}+\text{Wp}(t),\\
\frac{\partial \text{Phi}(t)}{\partial t}&=\frac{(c\times \text{Sigma})}{\pi\times  L\times \text{Omega}^2}\text{NN}(t) \times(\text{Phi}(t)+1)-\frac{\text{Phi}(t)}{\text{Tauph}}
\end{align}$$
and.

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Wp}(t)=\frac{(2 \text{Ep})}{\sqrt{2 \pi }\times h\times \text{Nu}\times \text{Tauph}} (1-\exp (-\text{Alpha}\times l)) \exp \left(-\frac{2 t^2 \log (2)}{\text{T0}^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$

I have the code below,

```
Clear["Global`*"]
c = 3 10^8(*m/s*);
Sigma = 2.96 10^-23(*m^2*);(*2.96 10^-19cm^2*);
Omega = 1.4 10^-3(*m*);(*1.4 mm*);
L = 330 10^-3(*m*);(*330 mm*);
Tau0 = 3.2 10^-6(*s*);(*3.2 \[Mu]s*);
Ep = 37 10^-3(*J*);(*37 mJ*);
h = 6.62607015 10^-34 (*J s*);
Nu = 10(*Hz*);
Alpha = 1 10^2(*m^-1*);(*1 cm^-1*);
l = 25.4 10^-3(*m*);(*25.4 mm*);
T0 = 11 10^-9(*s*);(*11 ns*);
Delta = 0.44;(*no unit*)
Tauph = L/(Delta c);
Wp[t_] := (2 Ep)/(Sqrt[2 Pi] Tauph h Nu) (1 - 
     Exp[-Alpha l]) Exp[(-2 Log[2] t^2)/T0^2];
slas = NDSolve[{D[NN[t], t] == 
     Wp[t] - (c Sigma)/(Pi Omega^2 L) NN[t] Phi[t] - NN[t]/Tau0, 
    D[Phi[t], t] == (c Sigma)/(Pi Omega^2 L) NN[t] (Phi[t] + 1) - 
      Phi[t]/Tauph, NN[0] == 0, Phi[0] == 0}, {NN, Phi}, {t, -1, 
    100}];
Plot[{Evaluate[NN[t] /. slas], Wp[t]}, {t, -50 10^-9, 100 10^-9}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

at the end I have the plot for $Wp(t)$ but $NN(t)$ gives the following errors such as:

```
NDSolve::nderr: Error test failure at t == 1.2601140976532838`*^-10; unable to continue.
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {-4.99969*10^-8} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
```

I tried different methods for `NDSolve`, non-dimensionalizing $t$ variable such that I can get rid off $10^{-9}$'s and see everything in terms of nanoseconds that didn't worked either. (I don't copy that code since it might overcrowd the question)

Is it about machine precision? Any ideas for what the problem is and how to solve it?

**Note:** I am trying to recreate a result from an article and NN(t) should give a gaussian.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try `Method -> {"Extrapolation", Method -> "LinearlyImplicitEuler"}`.  There is a singularity just to the negative side of `t == 0`, so I don't think you can get rid of the `dmval` error except by changing the domain to `{t, -3.99*10^-15,...}`.

Comment: The problem seems quite sensitive to changes in `WorkingPrecision`.  The (quasi) period seems stable, but not the amplitude and phase.  Unsure what to do next.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the parameters. At zero you get `eq /. t -> 0 /. NN[0] -> 0 /. Phi[0] -> 0 `  `{Derivative[1][NN][0] == 1.6416*10^39, 
 Derivative[1][Phi][0] == 0., True, True} ` ultrahigh derivative of NN.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, unfortunately the article has many mistakes. Still working on. I may erase this post, because it is not related with mathematica. What do you think?